# How to ARRAY_AGG two columns into one item in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Can anybody suggest how to convert this code into SQLAlchemy code?

```
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT (table.column_a, table.column_b)) AS label
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution

```
from sqlalchemy import func
func.array_agg(func.distinct(table.column_a, table.column_b)).label('my_label')
```

Comment: While this produces valid (Postgre)SQL syntax wise, how'd you instruct psycopg2/SQLA to parse the array of anonymous records produced by the row constructor?